Can I update feature type in a Databricks FeatureStore?
Is it possible to change schema of a Databricks Feature Store? I want to change the type of one feature, but I can't find anything in the documentation regarding such operations on individual features.
https://api-docs.databricks.com/python/feature-engineering/latest/feature_store.client.html#module-databricks.feature_store.client
